# 500 Internal server error. The first argument should be an array

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I am having a very weird issue on one site (www.theprinterdepo.com), in google chrome I am seeing a 500 internal server errror.
However on IE an firefox it works fine).
What I noticed is that if I go to chrome and click on history and remove all cache, cookies, etc, then it works  fine again.

I removed the system.log and checked again and the only thing logged is this one:

The first argument should be an array  in /xxx/xxx/public_html/app/code/local/Mf/Searchterms/Model/Layer.php

THis is a standard magento file that I have never touched, but here its the code:

```
<?php


class Mf_Searchterms_Model_Layer extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer
{
    const XML_PATH_DISPLAY_LAYER_COUNT = 'catalog/search/use_layered_navigation_count';

    /**
     * Get current layer product collection
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Resource_Product_Collection
     */
    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        if (isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
            $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];
        } else {
            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/fulltext_collection');
            $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()] = $collection;
        }
        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare product collection
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Resource_Product_Collection $collection
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer
     */
    public function prepareProductCollection($collection)
    {

        $params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();

        $collection
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes());
        $query = Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery();
        $productIds = Mage::getModel('searchterms/searchterms')->getProducts($query->getId());
        $productIds = array_filter($productIds);
        //var_dump($productIds);

        if(is_array($productIds) && sizeof($productIds) > 0){
            //echo "asd";
            $productIdArray = $productIds;
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$productIdArray));
            $collection->joinField('position',
                'searchterms_product',
                'position',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                'searchterms_id='.$query->getId(), 
                'left')
                ;

                if(isset($params['order']) && $params['order'] != ""){
                    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
                    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);
                }else{
                    $collection->setOrder(`searchterms_product`.'position','ASC');
                    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
                }
        }
        else 
        {
            $collection->addSearchFilter(Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getQueryText());
            $collection->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
                ->addMinimalPrice()
                ->addFinalPrice()
                ->addTaxPercents()
                ->addStoreFilter()
                ->addUrlRewrite();
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);
        }


        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get layer state key
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStateKey()
    {
        if ($this->_stateKey === null) {
            $this->_stateKey = 'Q_' . Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getId()
                . '_'. parent::getStateKey();
        }
        return $this->_stateKey;
    }

    /**
     * Get default tags for current layer state
     *
     * @param   array $additionalTags
     * @return  array
     */
    public function getStateTags(array $additionalTags = array())
    {
        $additionalTags = parent::getStateTags($additionalTags);
        $additionalTags[] = Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query::CACHE_TAG;
        return $additionalTags;
    }

    /**
     * Add filters to attribute collection
     *
     * @param   Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Resource_Product_Attribute_Collection $collection
     * @return  Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Resource_Product_Attribute_Collection
     */
    protected function _prepareAttributeCollection($collection)
    {
        $collection->addIsFilterableInSearchFilter()
            ->addVisibleFilter();
        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare attribute for use in layered navigation
     *
     * @param   Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute $attribute
     * @return  Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute
     */
    protected function _prepareAttribute($attribute)
    {
        $attribute = parent::_prepareAttribute($attribute);
        $attribute->setIsFilterable(Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute::OPTIONS_ONLY_WITH_RESULTS);
        return $attribute;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**
I managed to clean the apache error log, refreshed the browser and then this is the new text on the log:
 [client 83.134.115.127] Premature end of script headers: index.php

Comment: There could be thousands of reasons for this. How you handle cookies, JS that is processed different way in different browsers, etc. Please, be more elaborate on how you present the problem - show some code, where does it says there is error, show that file/line.

Comment: 500 is an Apache error not a php one, look in the Apache logs

Comment: it says the error is on line 40, which is $productIds = array_filter($productIds);

Comment: I have the apache error log, I searched my ip in the logs but didnt find anything

Comment: @Veseliq please see my update 1, its the error in the apache log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably first line (`Mage::..`) returns `NULL` or `FALSE` when result set is empty and array_filter requires array, not null/false value! Try this:

```
$productIds = Mage::getModel('searchterms/searchterms')->getProducts($query->getId());
if (!$productIds) {
    $productIds = array();
}
$productIds = array_filter($productIds);
```

But this is (probably) a wrong way to use `array_filter`. Without second argument, it would filter any array elements that evaluate to `false`, eg if an element is `null`, `false`, `empty array`, `empty string`. But I doubt that `Mage::getModel(...)->getProducts(...);` would ever return such elements (without any knowledge for the particular case). But if it does return array with such elements, it is a sign of bad design behind it.

Comment: thanks, I made the edit on the code, and after clearing the system.log its never thrown again, however the 500 internal server error still occurs on chrome only, I have the apache error log but I have no idea what exactly to check.

Comment: This could be a big suphp log file or something completely different. Contact your host support, if you are not hosting the scripts yourself.